# CRM convertion from decimal hour to normal hour

Tags: javascript, crm

I'm trying to use the function `Split()` to separate before and after the "." so that I can transform the decimal minutes to normal minutes.

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
function formataHora() {
    //first i get the value in minutes
    var duracaoEmMinutos = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("smart_duracaodoevento").getValue();
    //from minutes to hours
    var emHoras = duracaoEmMinutos / 60;
    //i'm getting like 2.80 hours, so i'm trying to use spli(".") to separate 2 from 80
    var horaSeparada = emHoras.split(".")
    var minutosMaisSegundos = horaSeparada[1] * 60;
    //separating minutes from seconds
    var minutos = minutosMaisSegundos.split(".");
    //putting formated hour plus minutes together
    var horaFormatada = horaSeparada[0] + "," + minutos[0];
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("smart_duracaodoevento").setValue(horaFormatada);
}
```

When the script runs, I get the error: `TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'split' at formataHora`

Am I doing something wrong or CRM really does not support `Split()` function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to split a number.

This tweak will solve the error:

```
var horaSeparada = emHoras.toString().split(".");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex, i did the tweak and now i'm getting the error: ReferenceError: 'horasSeparadas' is undefined
   at formataHora